# Dynamically get count of each unique value in column

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

In my database, I have two columns: Email and Link.

In my form, everytime the user clicks a link, the user's email will be saved to the database along with the link he/she clicked (in the form of "#link").

I already got that. But how do I query the count for each link? I know it's something like:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT email) FROM db WHERE link = '#link1'
```

and the same query for #link2.

**But the links changes per week.** So how do I make the query more dynamic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Build a stored procedure and use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT link, COUNT(DISTINCT email) FROM db GROUP BY link
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT link, count(DISTINCT email)
FROM db 
GROUP BY link;
```